# Send items to trash

Tags: php, mysql

I want to implement a moderator feature on my website and i wonder what is the best practice to "send to trash" the data. I want to moderate users, pictures, comments etc. The issue is that in case one of moderators gets nuts and start deleting random stuff i can easily restore the data.

I was thinking duplicating all the tables, like table users, duplicate to users_trash and when someones deletes the user i duplicate the exact row to users_trash. Then when i want to restore a user i just move the row back to the main table. It looks like an efficient solution but is it the best practice?

Please tell me other suggestions you are thinking of.

PS: I am using MySQL and PHP for my website.

PS2: I don't want to add a new column to my tables like "visible" because i have millions of rows and another condition to my queries will just make them slowly and there are a lot of places to modify :)

Thank you

Comment: I'd add a flag `deleted` to every table and set it to 1 after "deleting".

Comment: Why not just have a status field on every item you can delete? A boolean, called 'isDeleted'? It means you don't need to duplicate your entire database structure.

Comment: Just added a second PS2 :) Please see why there. Thank you for your comments

Comment: Just adding a `deleted` flag, however, would not prevent malicious moderators from trashing data by modifying it to muck. For instance, if I replaced email addresses with 'reggie@reggie.reggie', that would want to be reverted!

Comment: @ChrisForrence - with that and his second PS, I think the best bet is regular backups.

Comment: @keepwalking PS2: if an additional columns slows down your database that much, you should set proper indices. There is a variety of PHP software that uses the solution with a `deleted` column and they are (mostly) working like a charm.

Comment: Regular backups on millions of rows will be pretty hard :) And of course, i dont want to recover all deleted rows.

Comment: @andrewsi - Either regular backups or by using revision triggers (which would increase the storage space needed by a lot)

Comment: @feeela of course i am using index but i will have to create a new and i don't want to overload the table. I know it can be optimized but still, this is not a recovery solution. I want to recover all the original data. If they change the title of the picture i will never be able to recover it.

Comment: The issue with `deleted` flags of some sort is that it makes queries more difficult. An alternative where you move deleted records to another table means that foreign key constraints could make things very hard. Also, when you delete a user, what do you do with related records?

Comment: I want to recover all the original data => for this i think regular backup is still the best.

Comment: What if you need to add another column? With two tables you need two columns. Also, foreign key constraints can lead to trouble with duplicate tables. I'd go with a flag column, it has a neglible effect on query speeds with proper indexing.

Comment: @keepwalking Which is a requirement for proper versioning, which also could be done in the same table. Try to figure out how this is done in systems like TYPO3 or Magento, both used on many sites with heavy loads and running just fine. Using a separate backup, introduces other drawbacks, like not being able to restore a revision in an easy way.

Comment: what's hard about regularly backing up millions of rows?

Comment: @sgroves if i moderate 20 pictures between backups and i only want to restore 2 rows? I have to restore the old backup and then delete the 18 pictures again. Looks a lot of hard work and a lot of backups.

Comment: @keepwalking You could also use a separate table to track the revisions, as it is done in [MediaWiki's](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/MediaWiki) `revision` table. As I said above, just check what other have done before re-inventing the wheel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If disk space is less of an issue than needing this and you also want to restore after a malicious UPDATE command, what you can do is create triggers to save all subsequent changes from your original table to a separate table. Note, however, that this will save an entry for EACH revision on your table.

It would look something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE rev_users
(
   id INTEGER NOT NULL,
   username VARCHAR(45),
   picLink VARCHAR(45),
   revId INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   action CHAR(6) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY(revId)
);
CREATE TRIGGER rev_users_i AFTER INSERT ON users FOR EACH ROW BEGIN 
  INSERT INTO rev_users (id, username, picLink, action)
  VALUES (NEW.id, NEW.username, NEW.picLink, 'INSERT');
END;

CREATE TRIGGER rev_users_u AFTER UPDATE ON users FOR EACH ROW BEGIN 
  INSERT INTO rev_users (id, username, picLink, action)
  VALUES (NEW.id, NEW.username, NEW.picLink, 'UPDATE');
END;

CREATE TRIGGER rev_users_d BEFORE DELETE ON users FOR EACH ROW BEGIN 
  INSERT INTO rev_users (id, username, picLink, action)
  VALUES (OLD.id, OLD.username, OLD.picLink, 'DELETE');
END;
```

Comment: Thank you, this looks very good :)

Answer (score 1):

Creating duplicate tables is not the way to go... You're going to increase the size of your database tremendously.

Instead, create a new table called "trash" or something of the sort and have the following structure:

**Proposed Structure**

```
id        date       table        data
int       DATETIME   VARCHAR      TEXT
```

When items are deleted from the website, create a new row in the trash table with 'table' being the name of the table the record is removed from, and 'data' should contain a serialized array of the data that was deleted.

**Restore Procedures**

Create a php script to restore items from this table by reinserting the row from the 'table' column, deserializing the 'data' field as your source of removed data.

Bob's your uncle, you have a quick way to restore things from ANY table without having dozens (or more) duplicates.

**Example Record**

```
1    01-01-2013 12:00:00    users    a:2:{s:2:"id";i:1234;s:4:"name";s:3:"bob";}
```

This example was deleted on 01-01-2013 from the `users` table with id = 1234 and name = bob.

Comment: Really, serialized data in old revisions?

Comment: Hmmm ... i can play with this a little. Because users also have pictures and pictures have comments. And maybe i just want to restore certain pictures to certain users ... same with comments.

Comment: Serialized is the best way to go without having some EAV structure. Keep it clean and removed dated items from the table often and it wont be a concern.